# Modules duplication with webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

How to treat module duplication across bundles with webpack V4 ?

If a "module A" have a dependency "module C" and generate a bundle "index.js".
If a "module B" have a dependency "module C" (same version) and generate a bundle "index.js".

If a "module D" have a dependency with both bundle "module A" and bundle "module B" : with an inspection of the bundle generated, I can see that the "module C" code is duplicated.

What is the solution to eliminate the duplicate code across differents bundles ?

EDIT :
My webpack config :

```
var path = require('path');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;


var webpackConfigManager = function(){

    let outDir = path.join(process.cwd(), "dist");
    let inPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/index.js')

    let config = {
        mode: 'production', 
        devtool:false,
        plugins: [
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
          ],
        entry: [inPath],
        output: {
            path: outDir,
            filename: 'index.js',
            libraryTarget: "umd" 
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
            symlinks:false
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    enforce: "pre",
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
                    loader: "eslint-loader",
                },
                {
                    test: /\.s?css$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: false,
                            importLoaders: 2,
                            sourceMap: true,
                            localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]"
                        }
                    },
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                includePaths: ['./']
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
                    use: {
                      loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    };

    return config;
}

module.exports = env => {
return webpackConfigManager();
};
```

example of import :

```
import MyComponent from "@myscope/myReactComponent";
```

Comment: Seems like you're not doing [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) correctly.

Comment: Tree shaking aims to delete the code not used, isn't it ? For my part, all the code of "module C" is used in both "module A" and  "module B"

Comment: Tree shaking removes unused code and should remove duplicated code as well. Or at least identify common modules and put it in a common bundle.

Comment: plz show your webpack config

Comment: Can you also share your import/require statements?

Comment: you need code splitting, i.e: SplitChunks.

Comment: I provide the config and example of import in my original post.

Comment: Concerning SplitChunks, I tried it without success. Does it work across bundles ?